# how can i pass userToken from login to app component react native

Tags: react-native

hi i am trying to make a login screen , but just dont understand how can i update the userToken state in my login component and after that pass it to the app component witch it is the one who will let me access to the singin screens

```
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const [userToken,setUserToken] = useState('')
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
  const onEndGetDatos = (payload) => {
    setUserToken(payload.data.id)
  };

  const sendDataL = () => {
    Axios.post('http://3.90.64.114/api/v1/web/login',{
        email,
        password
    }
    ).then(response => {
        onEndGetDatos(response);
    }).catch(err => {
        alert(err);
    })
  }
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView>
          <TextInput placeholder="Usuario(email)"
            onChangeText={email => setEmail(email)}
            keyboardType = 'email-address'
          />
          <TextInput placeholder="Contraseña" 
            secureTextEntry={true} 
            onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}/>
          <Button title="Entrar" onPress={sendDataL}/>
          <Button title="Olvide mi Contraseña" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Restablecer')}/>
          <Button title="Soy Nuevo" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Registrar')}/>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

how can i pass the userToken to my app component

```
const App = ({userToken}) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {userToken == null ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Restablecer" component={RestablecerPasswd} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registrar" component={RegistrarNewUsr} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Perfil" component={Perfil} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Configuraciones" component={CambiarPsswd} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Dietas" component={Dietas} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Datos" component={Data} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Async Storage to store the token and later on you can use it anywhere you want. With Async Storage you can Set or Get value by the key you have defined for you token.

set value:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

get value:

```
await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
```

for more available methods: [visit this documentation](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/)

Answer (score 0):

By this way, you'll need to pass the token manually on all screens. For a convenient way, you can store/retrieve the access token using [react-native-shared-preference](https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences#readme). The way you can access the token is, You can create a `Context` and wrap the app's root component to `Provider`.The context will expose the token and you can access it from anywhere. By using context, you won't need to retrieve the token from shared preference, You can retrieve and store the token in `Context` on app initializes which will be accessible throughout the app flow.